# Why is Physics SE so bad at sorting answers?

Tags: support

For instance take a look at this question:

[What technology can result from such expensive experiment as undertaken in CERN?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135764/what-technology-can-result-from-such-expensive-experiment-as-undertaken-in-cern)

Currently the top most answer has just 2 upvotes while a couple of 30-odd upvoted answers and even a 50 upvote answer is simply hidden away at the bottom. I'm finding this a recurring feature in several questions and it always puzzles me! Why doesn't Physics SE sort answers the same way as other SE sites?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have probably accidentally clicked the feature where the answers are ordered according to activity rather than votes. To order according to votes, click on the 'votes' icon (rather than the 'active' and 'oldest' icons) at the place where the question ends and the answers begin.

> [image: sorting answers]